# How to modify form fields with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have a big form with lots fields, now I want to use JavaScript to simplify the fields, that means, pre process and delete some of the fields with JavaScript then return a new processed field.

For example, I have fields in the form like `plot_country`, `plot_state`, `plot_city`, what I want to do is to precalculate the `location_#` from the `country, state, city` in JavaScript, and return the GET fields just contain `location_#`.

In this way the url will be simplified, and the server can directly use the location_# and it doesn't need to process the location combinations any more.

Does anyone have some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: code? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<form id="location_form">
<input type="text" id="plot_country">
<input type="text" id="plot_state">
<input type="text" id="plot_city">
<input type="hidden" id="location">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#location_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
       $('#location').value($(this).serialize());
       $('input[type=text]').remove();
    });
</script>
```